# Importing/Exporting data from Access to a remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, remote-access, mysql-connector

I am needing to know if there is a way to export data from a Access table to a Remote MySQL Server.

I have been able to successfully do it using Localhost:3306 for testing purposes using the MySQL connector and it works great, however I want to be able to update a table on a remote server for a project I am working on.

The remote server has a static IP address and uses port 3306 just as my local dB.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance,
Curtis

Answer (score 1):

You just replace localhost with the IP address, like:

```
122.133.144.155:3306
```

Answer (score 0):

This little tool is really useful.
http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php